# ComboBox null value does not copy to databound datasource

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, combobox, datasource

I have `ComboBox` databound to `BindingSource`. It works well except one case. When I erase text in `ComboBox` it happens that `ComboBox.SelectedIndex=-1` and `ComboBox.SelectedValue=null`, which is correct. Problem is that `DataSource` property bound to `ComboBox.SelectedValue` is not updated with the null value but it keeps the previous selection.

Here are fragments of code that might be important.

`ComboBox.DropDownStyle=DropDown;` I want `ComboBox` to be editable

`BindingSource.DataSource=oneRowDataTable;` `oneRowDataTable` means that this table has always 1 row of data

`ComboBox.DataBindings.Add("SelectedValue", BindingSource, "InvoiceID");` `ComboBox.SelectedValue` is mapped to `BindingSource`, it works well when I choose from existing values in `ComboBox`

This is [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370375/combobox-with-null-value-selecteditem-binding)  with similar problem but it did not help me.

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: he is in windows forms so there is no AutoPostBack !!

Comment: I see there is unfortunatelly no progress. The only idea I have got is to put event handler on ComboBox.SelectedValueChanged and do the job manually. @Davide Piras

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked this question on Micorosft forum as well. I have got this answer [MSND forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/06c0976f-14f8-4b7b-bb4f-ec3d96b1f23d). It is practically the same solution as I mentioned in my comment. I am going to live with this solution and I will see how it works.